# Rewrite & SSL on Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

I have a website configured for SSL on Apache as a virtualhost. The SSL configuration is working fine and for https://www.optimise.co.id. However, if a user arrives on http://optimise.co.id I want it to forward onto https://www.optimise.co.id - at the moment its stopping on https://optimise.co.id showing an invalid certificate (which it would as its only valid for the www.)

I've included the virtualhost configuration below. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot ######
RewriteEngine On
ServerName www.optimise.co.id
ServerAlias optimise.co.id
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /var/www/certificates/#####.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/certificates/#####.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/certificates/####.crt
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot ######
RewriteEngine On
ServerName www.optimise.co.id
ServerAlias optimise.co.id
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect the optimise.co.id to the www.optimise.co.id in the SSL VHost, and you do not need mod_rewrite on non-SSL VHost: see [apache doc](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL). Just redirect everything that comes on non-SSL to the SSL VHost with www.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot ######
    RewriteEngine On
    ServerName www.optimise.co.id
    ServerAlias optimise.co.id
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /var/www/certificates/#####.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/certificates/#####.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/certificates/####.crt

    # redirect everything to host to www.host :
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^optimise.co.id
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.optimise.co.id/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.optimise.co.id
    ServerAlias optimise.co.id
    Redirect permanent / https://www.optimise.co.id/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's worked. https://optimise.co.id still throws an SSL warning but this is because the SSL certificate is only valid for the www.

Comment: @GilesHunt You're welcome, glad it helped. For the SSL warning, did you try the proposal for the VirtualHost *:80 ? And there exists some SSL certificates that are not wildcard certificates but that accept both domains with www and without. May be try to checkout this when you will renew the certificate.

Comment: Yes port 80 is working fine thanks with your example.